# PhoneGap + jQM on Android: back button breaks page

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm experiencing a very odd issue. My PhoneGap app uses jQM for the UI.

On the first page I have fixed header and footers and a listview with embedded search field:

[...]

```
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="main-calls-div">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Cerca" id="main-calls-list" data-icon="false">
                    <!-- Dinamically created on JS -->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I run the app it works fine, but as I tap the search field and hit the physical back button of the device the whole page breaks: it seems "larger" and scrolls horizontally, furthermore the header is not fixed anymore and scrolls with content.

Issue is present with the following versions:

- PhoneGap 2.7 and 2.9
- jQuery 1.10.1 and 2.0.2
- jQuery Mobile 1.3.1

*** EDIT ***

I've narrowed down the problem: when clicking on the search field the  element receives the focus. When pressing the back button it does not lose it, thus causing the problem.

Here's a small Eclipse project showing the issue:

http://dev.mobimentum.it/jsfiddle/test-17349904.zip

After importing, run the project on an Android device, to reproduce the problem:

- try scrolling the listview, notice that the header is fixed at top
- click on the search field
- hit the back button (physical)
- try scrolling again, the header is not fixed anymore
- notice that the input field still has a glow indicating the focus

*** /EDIT ***

Any one encountered the same issue before?

Thanks,
Maurizio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in knowing a workaround for this issue, I've intercepted the keyboard hidden event and simulated a click to release focus from the input element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var curWindow = $(window);
    var initialHeight = curWindow.height();
    curWindow.resize(function() {
        console.log("resize: height="+curWindow.height());
        if (curWindow.height() == initialHeight) {
            $('.ui-focus').removeClass('ui-focus');
            $('.ui-content', $.mobile.activePage).trigger('click');
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#div[data-role=page]").each(function() {
   $(this).fixedtoolbar({ tap: true }); 
});
```

And I think you need use the next meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```